# Python list of combinations of positions

Tags: python, combinations

I'm trying to generate a list of all possible 1-dimensional positions for an arbitrary number of identical objects.  I want it formatted so each coordinate is the distance from the previous object, so for 3 objects (0,5,2) would mean one object is at position 0, another is at position 5 and another is at position 7.

So the main restraint is that the sum of the coordinates is <=D.  Nested for loops works well for this.  For example, with 3 objects with maximum coordinate D:

```
def positions(D):
    output=[]
    for i in range(D+1):
        for j in range(D+1-i):
            for k in range(D+1-i-j):
                 output.append((i,j,k))
     return(output)
```

What's the best way to extend this to an arbitrary number of objects?  I can't find a good way without explicitly writing a specific number of for loops.

Comment: using  `itertools.combinations`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can combine `itertools.combinations`, which will give you the locations, with taking the difference, which should give you your "distance from the previous object" behaviour.  For example, using

```
def diff(loc):
    return [y-x for x,y in zip((0,) + loc, loc)]
```

we have

```
In [114]: list(itertools.combinations(range(4), 3))
Out[114]: [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

for the possible *positions*, and then

```
In [115]: [diff(x) for x in itertools.combinations(range(4), 3)]
Out[115]: [[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

for your relative-distance version.